# Combine Multiple Lines of Output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently working on a basic Pig Latin translator as one of my first projects, it has been going pretty smooth until I got to translating multiple words. The input is `raw_input().split()` to create a list that can be easily used in a loop.

```
def sentfunc(x):
    if len(x) > 0:
        for word in x:
            first = word[0]
            new_sent = word + first + pyg
            new_sent = new_sent[1:len(new_sent)]
            print new_sent
```

I have tried `.join()` and also tried other methods listed on Overflow. I figured `.join()` wouldn't work because it is a loop for each word. Can anyone help me out? Sorry if I look dumb for asking this, I'm new

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `print`ing every iteration, you can create a list, then append each word to that list. You can then `join` the list and `print` the result.

```py
def sentfunc(x):
    result = []
    
    if len(x) > 0:
        for word in x:
            first = word[0]
            new_sent = word + first + pyg
            new_sent = new_sent[1:len(new_sent)]
            result.append(new_sent)
    
    print ' '.join(result)
```

Note that this is also noticeably faster than printing each iteration for large amounts of words.

Comment: Completely forgot that I could do that. That's what happens when you don't do anything for 6 months . Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `,` at the end of your `print` statement, it will not print out the ending newline.

```
print new_sent,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import Python 3's `print_function` in Python 2.7 by using a future import.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

The future imports must be at the top to work.

Then you can use the `end` and `sep` keyword arguments like in Python 3. This lets you change the print ending from the default `"\n"` to something else, like `""`.

```
print(new_sent, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a convenience for writing text to a "file", (stdout by default, but you can specify a different one).

But if you import `stdout` from `sys`, you can call its `.write()` method directly, which gives you more control. Unlike `print`, it doesn't add a newline for you. (Note that due to buffering, you may have to call `.flush()` before you see it in the console.)